# Registering Startup Script and Server Events

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, registerstartupscript

Someone please help me understand why RegisterStartupScript does not work in certain instances where there is also server code executing.  For example, let's say I have button1, and on the onclick event looks like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "whatever", "alert('hello')", true);
}
```

This will execute with no issues and I will receive a popup saying "hello".  However, if I have something like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ConvertToPDF(pdfFileName, pdfFilePath);
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "whatever", "alert('hello')", true);
}
```

This will not execute -- for what seems to be because there is a server event also firing before the javascript event.

Yet, this will work:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Session("MySessionVariable") = textBox1.Text;
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "whatever", "alert('hello')", true);
}
```

Doesn't assigning a session variable use server processing, so why does this work?

Here is the ConvertToPDF method which seems to kill things:

```
   public void ConvertToPDF(string pdfFileName, string docPath)
    {
        ApplicationClass wordApplication = new ApplicationClass();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = null;

        object paramSourceDocPath = docPath;
        object paramMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object isVisible = true;
        object isReadonly = false;

        string paramExportFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Docs"] + pdfFileName + ".pdf");
        WdExportFormat paramExportFormat = WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF;

        bool paramOpenAfterExport = false;
        WdExportOptimizeFor paramExportOptimizeFor = WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint;
        WdExportRange paramExportRange = WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument;

        int paramStartPage = 0;
        int paramEndPage = 0;

        WdExportItem paramExportItem = WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent;
        bool paramIncludeDocProps = true;

        bool paramKeepIRM = true;
        WdExportCreateBookmarks paramCreateBookmarks =

        WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateWordBookmarks;
        bool paramDocStructureTags = true;

        bool paramBitmapMissingFonts = true;
        bool paramUseISO19005_1 = false;

        try
        {

            // Open the source document.

            wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(

            ref paramSourceDocPath, ref paramMissing, ref isReadonly,
            ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,

            ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
            ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,

            ref isVisible, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
            ref paramMissing);

            // Export it in the specified format.

            if (wordDocument != null)
                wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(paramExportFilePath,

                paramExportFormat, paramOpenAfterExport,

                paramExportOptimizeFor, paramExportRange, paramStartPage,

                paramEndPage, paramExportItem, paramIncludeDocProps,

                paramKeepIRM, paramCreateBookmarks, paramDocStructureTags,

                paramBitmapMissingFonts, paramUseISO19005_1,

                ref paramMissing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          // logging code
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close and release the Document object.

            if (wordDocument != null)
            {
                wordDocument.SaveAs(ref paramSourceDocPath, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                    ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                    ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing);

                ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)wordDocument).Close(ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                 ref paramMissing);

                wordDocument = null;
            }

            // Quit Word and release the ApplicationClass object.

            if (wordApplication != null)
            {

                wordApplication.Quit(ref  paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing);

                wordApplication = null;
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your DoServerMethodProcess() code

Comment: I reposted the code and changed the DoServerMethodProcess code to the real code which is actually converting a word doc to pdf.

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "whatever", "alert('hello')", true); code don't wait.. till ConvertToPDF() complete..

Comment: What do you mean "code don't wait"?  It's executing before/during the server method?  Even so, why won't an alert pop up?

Comment: try to write at last line in ConvertToPDF() method

Comment: Are you trying to display an alert to the user after PDF file was generated (Save As/Open) prompt is displayed by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Since exporting PDF sends data to output stream, effectively preventing normal page lifecycle, it's a bit complicated than that. Here're basic steps to achieve desired effect:

1. On `Button1` *ClientClick* event kick off `setInterval` function,that would periodically check for a specific cookie value
2. On server-side code after Export is complete use Response.AppendCookie to send the cookie.
3. Back in client the setInteval function receives the expected cookie and that's your flag to execute additionalclient-side code (alert user, hide progress indidicator etc.)

Comment: I found that deep in the onion of my code, there was a call to "Response.flush() and Response.End()"  These both seemingly ended the execution of the javascript.  When I replaced the response command I was able to execute the javascript.  Thanks for everyone's time.